# Does any given integer only occur in one primitive Pythagorean triple?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I know that all integers are part of *at least* one primitive triple. But can this statement be refined to *exactly* one? From looking at some lists of triples it seems to be true, but I have no clue where I'd start in showing it.

Update: I'm not sure what the etiquette is regarding actually changing the question altogether... hopefully this is alright. I realised I'm actually interested only in whether any numbers act as the *smallest* number in more than primitive triplet.

Comment: Are you asking whether there exists an integer that appears in only one primitive triple, or whether every integer appears in at most one primitive triple?

Comment: @carmichael561 The latter, edited for clarification

Comment: 9, 12, 15 and 12, 16, 20

Comment: What other triple than 3,4,5 does 3 occur in?

Comment: And 12 occurs in 12, 16,20 and 9,12,15 and 12,5,13..

Comment: @N74 $9, 12, 15$ is *not* a primitive triple - they're all divisible by $3$.

Comment: @fleablood Neither $12, 16, 20$ nor $9, 12, 15$ are primitive - divisible by $2$ and by $3$, respectively.

Comment: Neither 1 nor 2 are part of any triple unless you allow a,0,a to be a rtriple.  Which I don't.

Comment: The original question never said anything about primitive triples. N74 is not an idiot.

Comment: Is 1,2,6 members of any primitive triplets?

Comment: Well, duh.  The question originally never said primitive triplets.

Comment: @fleablood It did.

Comment: @fleablood Here is the text of the earliest version of this question (see the edit history if you doubt me): "**Does any integer only occur in one primitive Pythagorean triple?** I know that any integer must be part of at least one primitive triple. But can this statement be refined to exactly one? From looking at some lists of triples it seems to be true, but I have no clue where I'd start in showing it." The word "primitive" occurs twice, once in the title and once in the body. And I never called $N74$ (or you) an idiot.

Comment: All right I stand corrected.  5 is in 2 primitives and 1 and 2 are in none.

Comment: 5 occurs in 3,4,5 and in 5,12,13.

Comment: @user254665 That has already been noted by carmichael561 and by RobertZ in their answers below.

Comment: @user254665, I would upvote your comment, but it has exactly 5 votes now and 5 fits the comment so well.

Comment: You can see how find any and all sides that match if they exist [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880890/are-there-any-2-primitive-pythagorean-triples-who-share-a-common-leg/3238431#3238431).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, a number can appear as the smallest value in two distinct primitive triples. For example, $(57, 176, 185)$ and $(57, 1624, 1625)$.

In fact, choose any two relatively prime positive integers $p$ and $q$ with $q+1 < p < q(1+\sqrt{2})$ and having opposite parity. Then $p^2-q^2 < 2pq$, and $(a,b,c)=(p^2-q^2, 2pq, p^2+q^2)$ is a primitive triple. Another primitive triple with $a$ as smallest element can be derived from the generators $r=\frac{a+1}{2}, s=\frac{a-1}{2}$: 
$$(r^2-s^2, 2rs, r^2+s^2) = \left(a,\frac{a^2-1}{2}, \frac{a^2+1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: You might add that both of these triples are primitive.

Answer (score 16):

The example $(3,4,5)$ and $(5,12,13)$ shows that some positive integers can appear in more than one primitive triple.

Comment: D'oh, I managed to miss the most obvious one! Although as a probably more difficult follow up - is there a number that acts as $a$ (i.e. the smallest) in more than one primitive triplet? As opposed to being $a$ in one and $c$ in another. I now realise that's what I'm actually interested in anyway, I just didn't know it at the time of asking the question.

Comment: $a^2 =(c-b)(c+b) $ Any $a$ so expressible can be in two triples.  Example $15^2=2k+1$ so $15^2=(k+1 -k)(k +1 +k) $ and $(17-8)(17+8) $.  I think $a$ has to be odd and composite and that's sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

There are integers that are in more than one primitive triple. 
For example $5$ occurs in $(3,4,5)$ and $(5,12,13)$. The number
$65$ occurs in $(33,56,65)$, $(65,72,97)$ and $(63,16,65)$.

Comment: Your first example already occurs in carmichael561's answer above, but your second example is nice! +1.

Answer (score 3):

Any factorization of the even term into $2rs$ with $r,s$ relatively prime gives a triple with that term in it. For example, take $rs = 2\cdot3\cdot5$ and we get two triples

$$(6^2 - 5^2, 60, 6^2 + 5^2) = (11, 60, 61) $$
$$(10^2 - 3^2, 60, 10^2 + 3^2) = (91, 60, 109) $$
$$(15^2 - 2^2, 60, 15^2 + 2^2) = (221, 60, 229) $$

More generally, if we take $rs = 2\cdot3\cdot n$ where $\gcd(n,6) = 1$ and $n \neq 1$. Then, two triples where the even term appears as the smallest will be

$$ (12n, 4n^2 - 9, 4n^2 + 9) \qquad (12n, 9n^2 - 4, 9n^2 + 4) $$

Answer (score 2):

Let $1<n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ such that $n=a^2b$ where any prime divisor (if any) of $a$ is $\equiv 3\pmod 4,$ and every prime divisor of $b$ is $\equiv 1 \pmod 4 ,$ and $b>1.$ Then $n=c^2+d^2$ for some co-prime $c,d\in N,$ with $c,d$ not both odd.

But since $n=2m+1$ with $m\in N$ we have $n=(m+1)^2-m^2,$ and $\gcd (m,m+1)=1.$

So $n$ appears as one of the 2 smaller members in $((m+1)^2-m^2, 2m(m+1), (m+1)^2+m^2)$ and as the largest member in $(|c^2-d^2|,2cd,c^2+d^2).$ For Examples: $n=5, c=2,d=1,m=2.$ And $n=13, c=3,d=2,m=6.$

Answer (score 0):

Side $A$ will be the smallest whenever $m,n$ are very close together for Euclid's formula where $$A=m^2-n^2\quad B=2mn\quad C=m^2+n^2$$
We can find triples for any side $A\ge3$ by solving the A-function for $n$ and doing a defined finite search for values of $A,m$ that yield an integer.

$$A=m^2-n^2\implies n=\sqrt{m^2-A}\qquad where \qquad  \lceil\sqrt{A+1}\space\rceil \le m \le \biggl\lceil\frac{A}{2}\biggr\rceil$$
The lower limit ensures $m^2>A$ and the upper limit ensures $m-n\ge 1$. Examples:

$$A=3\implies 2\le m \le 2\qquad n=f(3,2)=1\qquad F(2,1)=(3,4,5)$$
$$A=5\implies 2\le m \le 3\qquad n=f(5,3)=2\qquad F(3,2)=(5,12,13)$$
$$A=7\implies 2\le m \le 4\qquad n=f(7,4)=3\qquad F(4,3)=(7,24,25)$$
$$A=9\implies 3\le m \le 5\qquad n=f(9,5)=4\qquad F(5,4)=(9,40,41)$$
$$A=11\implies 3\le m \le 6\qquad n=f(11,6)=5\qquad F(6,5)=(11,60,61)$$

Sometimes there is more than one triple but $A$ is not always the smallest.
$$A=105\implies 10\le m \le 53\qquad$$

$$ n=f(105,11)=4\qquad F(11,4)=(105,88,137)$$
$$n=f(105,13)=8\qquad F(13,8)=(105,208,233)$$
$$n=f(105,19)=16\qquad F(19,16)=(105,608,617)$$
$$n=f(105,53)=52\qquad F(53,52)=(105,5512,5513)$$